# Using a sparkcontext function for each element of the RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I need to read data from Elasticsearch using Pyspark. I am trying to device a flow in pyspark as follows -

i) Create rdd1
ii) foreach occurrence-in-rdd1
conf = {a dynamic value based on the element of the rdd1}
rdd2 = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD("org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormat",\
        "org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable", "org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable", conf=conf)

I realise that "foreach" will distribute work across the workers and try to invoke sc.newAPIHadoopRDD thereby resulting into an error that sc is not available on the workers.

Is there an alternate way to achieve the above?
Note - I need to use "newAPIHadoopRDD" as the rest of the processing depends upon it.

Comment: Yes. use `map()` in order to output what you want per record in the RDD, and then use the method `newAPIHadoopRDD()` on the resulting RDD.

Comment: Thanks your your suggestion Avihoo. Unfortunately, the newAPIHadoopRDD API works only with sc i.e. we need to use sc.newAPIHadoopRDD() and will run on the driver.                                                                       Also, we want it to run on the cluster and were hoping that there would be some way of serialising newAPIHadoopRDD() to the workers so that the processing is in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest RDD. If you want to loop over the result of `rdd1`, you have to `collect` it to the driver first.

```
val rdd1Result = rdd1.collect()
rdd1Result.foreach { v =>
  val conf = ...
  sc.newAPIHadoopRDD...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dikei. Appreciate your inputs.                                                      A few points which are issues -                                                                 i) "rdd1.collect" returns a list whereas ".foreach"  works on a RDD               ii) We would like this to run on the worker nodes for scalability. However, we suspect that the entire "rdd1Result" will be processed only on the driver node. Any suggestions to make it run in parallel on the worker nodes?

Comment: A scala List also has `foreach` method. It's impossible to access the SparkContext in the worker nodes.

Comment: Yes Dikei. We've realised that SparkContext cannot be accessed in worker nodes. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a RDD inside foreach and you should not try to do it.
Unless you're doing a join : in this case spark can handle two rdds, and if you think about it this is kind of all you need.

It looks like you are doing a theta-join.
Depending on your data you can probably circumvent the loop using an exact join with approximate values.

Comment: Thanks Marmouset.                                                                              We realised that we need to change our approach. As a result, we created a function which does something similar to what newAPIHadoopRDD() does. Our basic requirement was to query elasticsearch which we did in an alternate manner. We used Hadoop APIs for that. We passed this new function using .map to the RDD so that it will get executed on the worker nodes. This helped us achieve what we wanted i.e. i) query elasticsearch ii) do it in a scalable manner.